# Precision modifier as a variable in C

Tags: c

In my program the user inputs the number of decimal places he requires in an output. I save this input as deci. How do I use this variable *deci* as a precision modifier?

Sample: 
Input a number: 23.6788766
Input number of decimals: 2
Output: 23.67

Comment: Conventionally, 23.6788766 to two decimal places is 23.68, not 23.67.

Comment: @Luchian this is tagged as `C` and so...

Comment: @NikBougalis wasn't when I posted the comment (stealth edit)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Ahh. Oops! ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is C you can do:

```
float floatnumbervalue = 42.3456;
int numberofdecimals = 2;
printf("%.*f", numberofdecimals, floatnumbervalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

In C, for example to change the default precision of 6 digits to 8:

```
int precision = 8;

printf("%.*f\n", precision, 1.23456789);
```

The precision argument has to be of type `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use * modifiers, as in the following examples of Wikipedia is explained:

> printf("%*d", 5, 10) will result in "   10" being printed, with a total width of 5 characters, and printf("%.*s", 3, "abcdef") will result in "abc" being printed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string